# Parse error at "__attribute__" QT Android

Tags: android, qt

I have a problem, about an error when running compiling Android 6.2 - 6.3. As shown below,

[image: 1]

Comment: Use text instead of image. Much easier to search for.

Answer (score 0):

this error mostly because you have 2 compiler path. that's mean you have installed mingW separately and with Qt installation. as you can see in your error codes Qt run the moc from this mingW path(C:\Qt\6.3.1...) and then it try to compile the app from other mingW compiler path(C:/MingW/...)
the solution is to remove the other mingW (that you install separately) from your variable path completely or just simply change the name of the other mingW folder to some thing else like mingWX that the Qt can not found it.